# Align ImageView to TextView baseline with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Is it possible to align the bottom of an `ImageView` to the baseline of a `TextView` using a `ConstraintLayout`? It used to be easy with a `RelativeLayout` but it seems to be gone from `ConstraintLayout`. :(

Answer (score 22):

yes, it can be achieved in constraintLayout using

```
android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
```

please check below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView33"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.815"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_96" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.59"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```