# How to align icon vertically to the center of the first line of textview in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I wanted to place my left icon(Please refer image below), vertically centred to first line of the text in TextView. I couldn't find a way, I tried **drawableLeft on text view, gravity & constraints** but that didn't help. Can anybody help me?

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_itm_tick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tick_mark"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_itm_tick"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Concepts of deep learning and machine learning workflow" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: just constraint your image to top and bottom of the text view. means top constraint of the image view to the top of text view and bottom to bottom

Comment: @SauravKumar In that case it will be vertically centre of whole paragraph not the first line.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** *For anyone who happens upon this answer: Not sure what I was thinking, but I believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50709378/6287910) is the right answer. In that answer, `android:baselineAlignBottom="true"` is used which actually an [attribute of ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:baselineAlignBottom).*

**Old answer:**
<s>If the *ImageView* were a *TextView* you could simply constrain its baseline to the baseline of the other *TextView*. Unfortunately, *ImageViews* don't really have a workable concept of baselines, so you can't simply constrain the baseline of the *ImageView* to the *TextView*. (Try it to see what happens.)</s> ****See update above.****

One way to go is to replace the *ImageView* with a *TextView*, set the icon as the *TextView's* background and constrain the two baselines. Without special consideration, this technique will result in scaling of the tick mark and will result in distortion. To get around this, place the tick mark drawable in a layer-list drawable and specify a gravity. It is the gravity that prevents scaling:

**tick_background.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tick_mark"
        android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

The tick mark can look like this:

**ic_tick_mark.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="#66A8DD"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M9,16.17L4.83,12l-1.42,1.41L9,19 21,7l-1.41,-1.41z" />
</vector>
```

The layer-list could also be an XML bitmap drawable if the underlying icon is a bitmap.

Another way, which will also work, is to create an empty *TextView* that has the same characteristics of the *TextView* you want to attach the tick mark to. Constrain the empty *TextView* to the baseline of the other *TextView*. This will position the empty textview alongside the first line of the other *TextView*.

Now, take the *ImageView* and constrain its top and bottom to the empty *TextView*. The tick mark will line up as is wanted.

This is an XML-only solution. Other solutions may involve some coding.

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_itm_tick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tick_mark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/dummyView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/dummyView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Concepts of deep learning and machine learning workflow"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dummyView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit your xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_itm_tick"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tick_mark"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Concepts of deep learning and machine learning workflow"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_itm_tick"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```